# EEG (P300) Signal Data Filtering for Noise Reduction

Tags: python, machine-learning, filter, dataset, data-cleaning

I have bulk EEG data(20000) which I convert them to P300 (Avarage of each 1000 raw represent 1 P300.  (I used Python for that)

My problem is about reducing the noise. I have trimmed %30 percent of my data because P300 signal starts to be visible after 300 ms. However, in my data there are noises. I would like to use filter get rid of my noises.

Here is some sample of my raw data ;

```
1.09863 -2.99072    0.549316    3.8147  
0.595093    -3.86047    -0.244141   3.32642 
0.183105    -2.59399    0.808716    2.28882 
-0.305176   -2.74658    2.10571 2.02942 
-0.991821   -4.3335 1.31226 2.09045 
-1.46484    -5.26428    0.686646    0.732422    
-1.75476    -4.47083    1.34277 -1.06812    
-2.05994    -3.60107    1.35803 -1.49536    
-2.88391    -2.99072    1.34277 -1.5564 
-3.98254    -3.20435    0.62561 -1.54114    
-4.76074    -1.89209    0.183105    -1.46484    
-4.57764    -0.930786   0.350952    -1.17493    
-3.58582    -3.11279    -0.62561    -0.457764   
-2.27356    -4.36401    -1.2207 -0.656128
```

Do you have any suggested and used simple filter for reducing the noise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a bandpass filter at (0.5, 50)Hz to filter out some noise before you do the average? The specific values would depend on what the noise consists of

Comment: I haven't tried it. I am still digging the net. :) Is it included in numpy library or do i have to code it by myself?

Comment: Not using numpy, but the scipy stack has everything you need to design and apply your own filters: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html

Comment: Not sure what the source of your data is, or what format its in, but theres also the MNE package which is designed specifically for EEG processing, although it might be more than what you need if youre just after filtering: https://martinos.org/mne/stable/index.html

Comment: As a software engineer, I am quite new to on Signal Processing but it seems quite fun for me. :) Thanks for your help in advance, I will write here the result after I apply the filter. :)

Comment: if you're getting data from openBCI, there are built-in filters you might want to add.